# AngularJS plugin for eclipse don't work

Tags: eclipse, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with eclipse and AngularJS. I made all like in this tutorials: 
1. http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/using-angularjs-in-eclipse-part-1.html
2. https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started#troubleshooting
3. http://javahonk.com/install-angularjs-plugin-eclipse/
But with all this I have the same problem...
My code looks like this
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sample">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="todo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Todo</h2>
<div ng-controller='TodoCtrl'>
<span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.lenght}} remaining</span>
 [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a>]
 <ul class="unstyled">
 <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
 <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <form ng-submit="addTodo()"></form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

todo.js

```
angular.module('sample', []).controller('TodoCtrl', function TodoCtrl($scope){
    $scope.todos=[
                  {text: 'learn angular', done:true},
                  {text: 'build an angular app', done:true}];
    $scope.addTodo= function(){
        $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText='';
    }
});
```

todo.css

```
done-true{
        text-decoration: line-through;
        color: grey;
}
```

I enviroment :
   - Eclipse kepler EE
   - Installed Angular 0.8.0 plugin (tried with 0.5.0 and 0.7.0 same problem)
   - Installed JSDT
   - Installed nodeJS and setted path in eclipse to the nodejs.exe file 
   - Script paths setted well 
   - Installed tern plugin

I have tested in the eclipse browser, chrom and mozilla... 
Please, have someone a solution to solve this problem :(

This is my output and code

[image: Output]

[image]

There have to be before "of remaining" and after that some text....

```
<span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.lenght}} remaining</span>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem with AngularJS Eclipse, completion doesn't work?

Comment: You've spelt `length` wrong in `todos.lenght`.